# How to access onRowDataBound event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, gridview

I am using `ListView` containing a `GridView` to bind the data. 
I want to do some work on each row during data bind but before displaying the complete data to UI.

This is general done in asp.net by `OnRowDataBound` event.

Is there any `OnRowDataBound` event that I can use in WPF. If so, how I can use it? Are there any alternatives to it.

Comment: As far as I now there is no event like `OnRowDataBound` in wpf. What you are planning to do in `OnRowDataBound` event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do, is in first place go through ValueConverter as intermediate step. It takes place in the process of DataBinding, between the source and the UIElement.

In your GridView, and in your GridViewColumn,  where you define your Path to the source, just add a ValueConverter matching the Type of data you want to bind to, and the return Type..

Then in the code of your valueConverter, do your changes.